# How to auto-start/eager start OSGi services on Eclipse platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I develop an Eclipse RCP application which makes heavy use of OSGi bundles which provide services for later use. The use case requires the bundles to register their services (e.g. import filters) to be used later on in different situations. The OSGi bundles are build with maven-bundle-plugin.

How can I tell Equinox to start the OSGi bundles automatically? The normal approach via Activator is not working. Only the lazy mode is working, but I can not touch classes within unknown bundles. I read the OSGi specification and the opposite to lazy load, eager load, is not provided. Is there another chance to mark the bundle for an auto load?

Within Eclipse I have a chance to set Auto-Start to true, but what do I do within a distribution build by Maven and Tycho?

Declarative services are not working due to the issue of a not loaded org.eclipse.equinox.ds. Can I get it started somehow instead of an Activator? This would be a solution, too, but I do not know how to build the distribution or what to set as configuration.

What are best practices here? Are there any other possibilities? The documentation on OSGi bundles on Eclipse platform is a little thin.

Comment: I don't know about maven/tycho. But if you use the pde ant script, it use a `config.ini` to control auto starts. Check the generated `config.ini` under `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\your-rcp-product-name.product` .

Comment: see http://software.2206966.n2.nabble.com/tycho-generated-config-ini-does-not-start-runtime-td6077893.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with declarative services. Registering your services manually is a lot like hard work, and looking them up safely can be even more work, and tricky to get right. Another standard in this area to be aware of is Blueprint, although I certainly don't suggest you rewrite anything if you have DS metadata in place. Blueprint has slightly nicer characteristics in a very dynamic environment, and a richer configuration. (I'm a committer on one of the Blueprint implementations, Apache Aries.) With both Blueprint and DS the important thing is that something else is managing your services for you.

This leaves us back with the issue of why your bundles aren't being started. I think there must be a clue in the fact that they do start in Felix. Have you fired up an equinox console and confirmed all your bundles are installed and resolved? ('ss' to list bundles.) 
Have you had a look in the config.ini file and confirmed your bundles are listed, and with an appropriate start level - or are you using the Equinox auto-start-everything else bundle?

Comment: Yes, I will try the declarative services next. I will tell later.

Comment: So, it was working. I let the DS start during runtime and let declare the services via XML. The services before were resolved and not started. How I can influence that, I do not know. But DS is working.

Answer (score 9):

Sigh. You're the victim of a misguided strategy in Eclipse to prevent (dumb) programmers from extending the startup time. Instead of warning, they just decided not to start bundles at all. This is the opposite of what OSGi recommends :-( A bundle could only get activated (they basically voided start) when somebody loaded a class from it (this is what lazy activation is.)

The by far best solution is to use Declarative Services. You can declare immediate services, which will be activated at startup, and you can declare lazy services, which get activated when used. The lazy are of course preferred (when you're not a dumb programmer) but certain use cases require immediate, like example a server that offers it services over the internet. You have to make sure in your config.ini that DS is started.

Comment: Yes, I already read about the different philosphies. I like and support lazy loading, but as you mentioned: Some designs need an auto loading to register services (whiteboard pattern). I will try the declarative services.

Comment: As you said, Eclipse normally won't start any bundle unless explicitly listed in the config or it uses lazy activation and has a class loaded by some other bundle. This is a problem for DS as stopped/installed bundles are ignored. However, I did notice that the Equinox Service Component Runtime has a hidden feature: if you declare your bundle as lazy-loading and your component is marked as "immediate", the SCR will start your bundle *for* you (most likely because SCR figures that if nobody started it, nobody else will). No idea yet about non-immediate behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "org.eclipse.ui.startup" extension point in your plugin. This allows you to specify an IStartup class that will be called when the Eclipse UI starts up. As long as this is a class in your bundle then your bundle will be started.

It will mean including a plugin.xml file, and this would be specifically an Eclipse plugin rather than a standard OSGi bundle, but you could then use this plugin to activate any of your standard OSGi bundles.

Comment: Some of the bundles I use are rather generic and I don't want to make them to eclipse plugins. I know, it's not an issue to bundle a plugin.xml and other files into the jar, but I think it's not really clean. Your suggestion is good and I think it will work, but it is my last choice, I think. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't think there's any need to modify your current bundles. The Eclipse plugin could simply be a new bundle with the sole job of ensuring that the DS bundle has started, that way your declarative services will all be found. This avoids having to specify startup bundles in the config.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `.product` file:

```
<configurations>
    <plugin id="my.plugin.id" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
</configurations>
```

Alternatively, open the `.product` file in Eclipse and go to the Configuration tab, and add the plugin with the desired start level there.

Answer (score -1):

MANIFEST.MF has this:

```
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

This could be also useful:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Lazy_Start_Bundles#Should_I_change_to_the_new_Bundle-ActivationPolicy_Header.3F

However I would say I would try relying on OSGI activation as much as possible. If there is no other way of solving your problem, then the previous link might help.

Comment: For lazy loading my application needs to know about the bundles to be activated. This is not wanted and not a good design. This is why I removed lazy loading. In Felix my bundles are activated correctly. Just Equinox makes some trouble. What I would need is 'Bundle-ActivationPolicy: auto', but this is not supported.