# OSGi Bundle not get resolved automatically

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, modularity

I have a simple OSGi bundle written and here is the source file. When I install it in a equinox OSGi container it does not get resolved it automatically. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here??.

```
package org.sample.api;

/**
* Created on 3/11/14.
*/
public interface Hello {

    void sayHello();
}
```

This is the pom.xml file of the bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
        <groupId>osgi</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>sample-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Vendor>Sample Inc</Bundle-Vendor>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.sample.api*;version=1.0.0
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1
Bnd-LastModified: 1396602001251
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Built-By: Zeus
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: sample-api
Bundle-SymbolicName: sample-api
Bundle-Vendor: Sample Inc
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: org.sample.api;version="1.0.0"
Tool: Bnd-1.43.0
```

This is the bundle installation console output

```
    Bundle id is 7
RegisteredServices   null
ServicesInUse        null
LoaderProxy          sample-api; bundle-version="1.0.0"
Fragments            null
ClassLoader          null
Version              1.0.0
LastModified         1396605985751
Headers               Bnd-LastModified = 1396602001251
 Build-Jdk = 1.6.0_45
 Built-By = Zeus
 Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
 Bundle-Name = sample-api
 Bundle-SymbolicName = sample-api
 Bundle-Vendor = Sample Inc
 Bundle-Version = 1.0.0
 Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
 Export-Package = org.sample.api;version="1.0.0"
 Manifest-Version = 1
 Tool = Bnd-1.43.0


BundleContext        null
BundleId             7
StartLevel           1
SymbolicName         sample-api
BundleData           sample-api_1.0.0
KeyHashCode          7
StateChanging        null
BundleDescription    sample-api_1.0.0
Framework            org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework@65cb687f
ResolutionFailureException org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "sample-api_1.0.0 [7]" could not be resolved
Revisions            [sample-api_1.0.0]
Key                  7
ProtectionDomain     null
Location             file:/home/Zeus/idea-projects/osgi/sample-api/target/sample-api-1.0.jar
State                2
Bundle                   7|Installed  |    1|sample-api (1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the generated MANIFEST.MF from the jar. I cant see anything wrong with the pom.

If the bundle is not resolved, in what state is it then? Installed? One possible reason could be that some of the transitive dependencies of the bundle are not available on the container.

P.S: You may want to use the latest version 2.4.0 for the maven-bundle-plugin.

**EDIT1**
This is the manifest I got:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1396605817562
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Built-By: anshuman
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: sample-api
Bundle-SymbolicName: sample-api
Bundle-Vendor: Sample Inc
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: org.sample.api;version="1.0.0"
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213

**EDIT2**
I hope you are refreshing and starting the bundle after you install it.
refresh 7
start 7
where 7 is your bundle id.

Comment: Added the manifest data. It's in the INSTALLED state. when using the "diag" command it says no No unresolved constraints.

Comment: It is not necessary, but to troubleshoot, you can add a Bundle-Activator and see if the start is invoked.

Comment: I tried to run your example on my machine (I am using Karaf, 2.4.0 of the bundle-plugin) and it works fine: 87 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0          | sample-api

Comment: I've added the installation console output. I've got a "ResolutionFailureException org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "sample-api_1.0.0 [7]" could not be resolved" Exception.

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675298/how-to-auto-start-eager-start-osgi-services-on-eclipse-platform

Comment: Isn't the bundle not get resolved automatically by the framework?. Do I have have to refresh it manually?.. After refresh it resolved without any problem..

Comment: AFAIK the purpose of install is to take the bundle to INSTALLED state which is exactly what is happening. There are admin commands to update (refresh) and start the bundle. If you want auto (hot) deployment, you can take a look at Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a Activator with your bundle, at least your given sample doesn't contain one and your output for the generated Manifest doesn't contain a Bundle-Activator part. At this point I'd say your bundle is just in resolved state since it can't be active.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALLED state is not an error condition. It just means that the bundle has been installed, which is true.

If you do see an actual error message, please provide the details.